# Slickedit: How can I set the language of the currently open file if it has no extension?

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on a file without an extension in Slickedit (over Linux). Because it has no extension, Slickedit doesn't identify what language the file is written in. Is there a way to manually define the language of the file in order to get the markups and supporting features of the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Document* menu, the option *Select Mode* allows to select the language.[image]